# How to change foreign key suffix in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

In EF Core with a code-first approach, by default column referencing another entity has an `Id` suffix - for example `PersonId`.

Is it possible - and if so, how? - to change it to `_id`, so to `person_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the foreign key explicitly under the name you want - in your case `Parent_Id`. Keep a `navigation property` and `foreign key` property.

```
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

Map the foreign key relations using `.HasForeignKey()`. Something similar as below

```
    builder.HasOne(d => d.Prop)
        .WithMany(p => p.NavigationProp)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ForeignKeyProp)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_ConstraintName");
```

If you prefer `data annotation`, you could also use

```
    [Column("Parent_ID")]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
```

Comment: The data annotation example should be `[Column("Parent_ID")]` not `[ForeignKey...]` ForeignKey is used to nominate what navigation property the FK field points to or which FK property a Navigation property should use.

Answer (score 0):

To add to WisdomSeeker's answer, you can use a `[ForeignKey]` annotation to point at a shadow property for the FK.

Given a class like a Course with a Person reference for a Teacher:

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // other fields.

    [ForeignKey("person_id")]
    public virtual Person Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatives as above would be:

```
[ForeignKey("Teacher")]
public int person_id { get; set; } // Not recommended naming convention in code.
public virtual Person Teacher { get; set; }
```

or

```
[Column("person_id"), ForeignKey("Teacher")]
public int TeacherId { get; set; }
public virtual Person Teacher { get; set; }
```

I generally avoid adding FK fields into classes as this leads to two sources of truth for what Teacher is assigned to a course. You have course.TeacherId and course.Teacher.Id, which could differ on update prior and after a `SaveChanges`. Shadow properties help avoid confusion and keep data updates consistent.

Using `[Column]` is common in Db-First implementations where you want to use a C# naming convention for properties to use in-code, but abide by existing/desired DB naming conventions in the database. I don't generally recommend using DB naming conventions in C# classes.